# IIS Failed To Run & XAMPP Anomally

Tags: apache, iis-7, xampp

I recently activate IIS7 feature in my Windows (through control panel)

Previously I already installed XAMPP in my machine (configured to run on port 8080 through the httpd.conf file)

What happen is:

1. I am not able to invoke the iis startpage.. (using address http://localhost/), doesn't display error or anything, jus a plain blank page..
2. on the other hand, when I tried to run my XAMPP, i noticed that on the control panel it is mentioned that  it's running on port 80 (which contrary to my settings)
3. However XAMPP startup page still can only be invoked through http://localhost:8080/xampp. I figured that if what the control panel telling me is true, I shouldn't need to include the ":8080"..

Can anyone give any idea how this happen? And how to fix this anomally, thx?

Comment: Stop XAMPP and see if that solves the problem.  If so, then you've got a port conflict.  You can also use TCPView to see which apps are using which ports.

Comment: I did try to stop.. I still can't view my iis start page..

Comment: Try TCPView and see if port 80 is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I some time ago successfully installed a IIS and XAMPP in a Windows (I use Windows 7 Ultimate) and both are running smoothly. But before installing XAMPP, I have activated & using IIS before. I'm using XAMPP 1.7.3.

Maybe you could try to install IIS first, XAMPP. Before installing XAMPP, make sure the IIS service is running / active.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You are saying that I just need to remove my xampp and reactivate my iis?

Comment: Yes, but it is recommended you backup File PHP & Databases in the htdocs folder (/ xampp / htdocs) and Data (/ xampp / mysql / data) first. Try to uninstall IIS and Xampp, restart your CPU, install the IIS again, check in http://localhost/, when the IIS logo's appears IIS means installation is successful. Restart again, just install XAMPP (try version 1.7.3).